# For whom does "upwards of" mean "less than, but approaching" ? Is it a regionalism?

Tags: meaning, idioms, dialects

The phrase *upwards of X* appears to be [defined very explicitly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upwards%20of) to 
mean simply and only “more than X”. (In other words, it is an exact
substitute for “north of”.)

I have a pernicious and deeply held understanding of the phrase as meaning 
“as much as X, but not more” or “trending upwards towards X” (in both of
these cases, the quantity in question is understood to be
slightly less than or maybe equal to X).

This is not merely a one-off personal error. I have informally polled family and friends, and have also polled [100+ people on Twitter](https://twitter.com/bzotto/status/946589530186018817), and it's clear that the understanding I have is common, if not the dominant understanding of the phrase.

I'm an American New Englander by upbringing, but I'm not sure what other context is useful. I have immediate family that swears by the dictionary definition, and others who are with me on this.

I'd be less interested if these were shades of meaning, but these are clear opposites of definition. Does anyone know what the distinction is in regions/dialects, or otherwise where this phrase comes from?

Comment: From my perspective it’s just a misunderstanding.  There are some UK vs US differences in phrases like “nearly missed” but I don’t see anything like that for your phrase.

Comment: 'I would dismiss this as just a simple dumb long-held misunderstanding'. Yep, this site does that to a lot of people. It happens to me about once a week.

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks for the edit cleanup, but I'm neither a scholar nor an aesthete, so to avoid such rote projects for you and others, perhaps the code formatting option could be removed from the ELU site? Also, although it's certainly your right to do it, I'm not sure everyone appreciates non-semantic edits to their already-grammatical writing just because you happen to prefer different wording or orthography.

Comment: @PhilSweet I'm certainly willing to believe that. It was the agreement of the friend that gave me pause and maybe we can both be disabused of the idea. :)

Comment: I am from San Francisco and, until now, shared this "simple, long held misunderstanding." I can't wait to correct my friends now and tell them, "Excuse me, but I think you meant to say, '*Downwards* of ...'"

Comment: Do please free to reëdit it back to your own liking (provided you not use code formatting on noncode:), but understand that community edits to improve formatting, punctuation, and wording are customary not just here but throughout the Stack Exchange Network. We’re trying to build up a library of expert answers to real questions people have to help future visitors to our site, so improving all posts, whether questions or answers, is something everyone pitches in on.

Comment: I wonder if this stems from the usage of "up to" or "up towards", which certainly mean "approaching, but hitting a maximum at X value" as opposed to the meaning of "upwards of" meaning "a value with a perceived minimum at X and possibly higher than X"

Comment: I haven't done or seen any scholarly linguistic mapping, but I've certainly traveled around New England quite a bit. I can confirm that the expression as reported has struck my ears and eyes often enough to suggest that it's at least a regional thing - more widespread than "bubbler" (bubblah) or "tonic", and possibly reaching beyond the Sox/Yankees boundary. Chee-ahs!

Comment: @tchrist Understood, and my appreciation for those who spend a lot of time proactively improving what's here; I have deeper history myself elsewhere on the network. I do think that at some point, when you find yourself changing "long-held" to "long held", you're doing something more personal than "improving" the wording; you're imposing a personal style guide on otherwise correct and intelligible bits of text. I'm here (in this case) to humbly ask for information. I don't want to also be told that I'm writing (correct) compound adjectives wrongly. I hope this is genuinely useful feedback. :)

Comment: @Rob_Ster - The question isn’t so much about whether the expression is common but rather for whom does it mean “less than but approaching” instead of “something higher than”

Comment: This is quite interesting. Thinking about it, I think I’ve always interpreted _upwards of_ as meaning “somewhere around, perhaps a bit more or less”, which is kind of a mixture of the two meanings described here. Even more interestingly, in my other native language of Danish, the equivalent expression _godt (og vel) X_ (‘a good X’, lit. ‘good (and well) X’) exhibits the same ambivalence: dictionaries define it as “X and a bit more”, but many people use it to mean “not quite X, but close”. Apparently I’m more on the dictionaries’ side in Danish than in English!

Answer (score 1):

I've always used "upwards of" to mean "at most, but close to". For example, if somebody said "the entrees at this restaurant cost upwards of $100", I would expect most entrees to be below $100, with a few at or maybe just slightly above $100. I was born and raised in Vancouver, BC.

Only today (at age 30) did somebody say to me "doesn't 'upwards' mean 'more than'?" which led me to this question.

My fiancé grew up around Atlanta, GA and uses 'upwards' in generally the same way as me.